# I have submitted a form for searching from db but it return with the error given

Tags: laravel

Error message:

> The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.

```
<form action="{{ route('searchitems') }}/#custom" method="post">
@csrf
....
```

web.php

```
Route::post('/searchitems',[App\Http\Controllers\ViewController::class, 'searchcourse'])->name('searchitems');
```

controller

```
public function searchcourse(Request $request)
{

 .....

        return view('frontend.indexElearning', ["userinfo" => $userinfo,]);              
        
    }

If made wrong then how it should be written for POST request?
Plese not (laravel version 9)
```

[image: 1]

Comment: Your form is not submitting POST request. It is submitting a GET request and that's what the error says - `The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST`.

Comment: Is csrf set in your form?

Comment: @brombeer If no csrf set it will print a PAGE EXPIRED error

Comment: clear the cache first to check if it is due to caching.

Comment: What is the version of laravel?